# Cannot find the issue why the output gives an unresolved error

Tags: c++

I am using the code from an old project of mine and wanted to use that code in one of my newer projects. So I literally copied and pasted the same code over to my new project solution. It works flawlessly in the old source, but in the new one it gives me the following error code:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression state
Error LNK2019 Reference to unresolved external symbol ""public: void __cdecl Hookxyz::Enable(void)" (?Enable@Hookxyz@@QEAAXXZ)" in function ""public: bool __cdecl rD3D11::HookD3D(void)" (?HookD3D@rD3D11@@QEAA_NXZ)". MyProject D:\MyProject\MyProject\rD3D11.obj 1
```

In case you need more code to help me out, here is how my structure looks like:

hook.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
class Hookxyz
{
public:

    BYTE* src{ nullptr };
    BYTE originalBytes[30]{ 0 };
    BYTE* dst{ nullptr };

    uintptr_t len{ 0 };
    uintptr_t* pTrampoline{ 0 };

    bool bEnabled{ false };
    void Enable();
};
```

hook.cpp:

```
#include "hook.h"
void Hookxyz::Enable()
{
    if (!bEnabled)
    {
        memcpy(originalBytes, src, len);
        * (uintptr_t*)pTrampoline = (uintptr_t)TrampHook64(src, dst, len);
        bEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

rD3D11.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "hook.h"
class rD3D11
{
public:
    Hookxyz presentHook;
};
```

D3D11.cpp:

```
#include "hook.h"
#include "rD3D11.h"
bool rD3D11::HookD3D()
{
    presentHook.Enable();
    return true;
}
```

What exactly is the issue? How can I solve this?

Comment: Most likely `hook.cpp` was not compiled and is not part of your Visual Studio project.

Comment: thanky you for your answer, I double checked it, yes it is part of the project and it gets compiled.

Comment: Do you have two projects?

Comment: I have 2 sources, a new one and an old one. I copied the code from my old source into the new source. All files are included so that shouldn't be the issue. And yes these are 2 different c++ projects which are not in the same solution/folder.

Comment: Maybe you need to build clean if the `hook.cpp` file is in the same project as `D3D11.cpp`. Also make sure that the hook.obj was created likely in the `D:\MyProject\MyProject` folder.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean with "build clean"? I I have cleaned up the project several times using the vs build tool, so this should not be a problem. Yes, the hook.cpp is in the same folder as the rD3D11.cpp, but in the old project its the same, and there it works. I think it is more likely somewhere in the code.

Comment: I don't think this is a code problem. It looks like a settings problem.

Comment: Okay. If i comment out the presentHook.Enable(); in rD3D11.cpp it compiles without any error, but then it ofc doesn't execute the hook. in case that helps you with the solving.

Comment: What happens if you intentionally put code errors in the `hook.cpp` file?

Comment: It doesn't build because of even more errors that are caused by the ones that i put inside the hook.cpp

Comment: I don't have a good explanation for this behavior. Someone else will have to help.

Comment: Okay thank you anyway for trying to help me out :).

Comment: Is hook.obj created in the same folder as D3D11.obj?

Comment: yes the hook.obj is in the same folder as the rD3D11.obj but as stated above that is also the case in my old project and it works flawless there.

Comment: Since the code works in your old project, the code itself is not the problem, and so is irrelevant. The problem is your project settings but we cannot see them.

Comment: *"yes it is part of the project and it gets compiled."* -- could you add the basis of this conclusion to the question? Copying (as text) the command used (by the build system) to link the project is one way to support this conclusion in the question.

Comment: In the past I had an issue with `#include <Windows.h>`,  not sure if it is the same. You can try to comment out that line. Compiler would raise an error for `BYTE not found`, try to `typedef unsigned char  BYTE;` at `hook.h` file.